# Cygwin flip command

Tags: cygwin, flip

Previous I was using flip command for MKS toolkit, but now I have cygwin with me. So Please let me know flip -dbc equivalent command in cygwin.
I have flip command, in cygwin. I am looking for the same behavior in cygwin which was provided by -dbc options in MKS toolkit.

Answer (score 0):

`flip -mb -` is almost equivalent (see cygwin flip [manpage](http://polarhome.com/service/man/?qf=flip&tf=2&of=Cygwin&sf=1)), you need to `cat` the file to `flip`, though.

From the MKS toolkit [manpage](https://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man1/flip.1.asp) for `flip`:

> -b  forces the conversion of files containing binary characters. Normally, flip returns an error if it encounters a binary character.
>
> -c  sends the converted results to standard output rather than overwriting the original file. This option is useful when working with
>   files for which you do not have write permissions, or when piping and
>   redirecting the output elsewhere.
>
> -d  converts file to use PC format line delimiters. This option changes all instances of a single Line Feed character into a Carriage
>   Return/Line Feed combination. Stand alone Carriage Returns are not
>   affected.

You could also write your own program to do it:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
/!\r$/
  {print $0 "\r"}
```

The above program appends a carriage return character to each line that does not have one before the newline character, emulating flip. It takes an input file.

You can save this to a file in your path, name it `flipper` and `chmod +x` it. To run your flipper:

First, we check our sample file has UNIX line endings:

```
$ file myTextFile.txt
/cygdrive/c/myTextFile.txt: ASCII text
```

Now we use the program to flip the file to a new file and check that the new file has DOS line endings:

```
$ flipper myTextFile.txt > myTextFile-fixed.txt
$ file myTextFile-fixed.txt
/cygdrive/c/myTextFile-fixed.txt: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
```

Testing without redirection:

```
$ flipper myTextFile.txt
Hello
World
!
```